# Настроить системную кнопку back в shortcuts

Tags: android, kotlin

Как то давненько создавал Shortcuts для приложения, кто не в курсе, вот [>ссылочка<](https://medium.com/@Marcus_fNk/android-7-1-shortcuts-under-5-minutes-247e3032779e). И всё вроде бы как good, но есть один маленький нюанс, при открытии одного из фрагментов, у меня по умолчанию открывается клавиатура. Так вот при нажатии системной кнопки back она у меня скрывается.

Сейчас же при переходе во фрагмент через shortcut и при попытке скрыть клавиатуру системной кнопкой back выкидывает на рабочий стол. Как возможно настроить корректную работу системной кнопки в shortcut'e?

**Примечание**:

Метод который отвечал за нажатие системной клавиши back:

```
override fun onBackPressed(): Boolean {
    if (numpadView?.visible ?: false) closeNumpadView() else activity?.finishFragment()
    return true
}
```

Был также переопределен в другой активити:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    finish()
}
```

Поэтому он меня вообщем то и выкидывал из приложения, но проблема осталась) Теперь если я к примеру удалю данный переопределенный метод, то у меня просто всё удаляет из фрагмента, а переносить тело из первого `onBackPressed()` не вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut как таковой тут совсем ни при чем. А что при чем, так иерархия активит и фрагментов в стеке. Явно при запуске через shortcut она у вас иная. Либо фокус иной, либо еще чего.

В эту сторону и надо копать.

Comment: Да, вы правы, вот дополнил вопрос примечанием(по-прежнему актуальным).

Comment: Разобрался, но ответ тут будет не совсем уместным.